# Problem - Simple Moderation model in R's Lavaan; Interaction term no variance

Tags: variance, interaction, missing-data, lavaan

I am attempting to run a simple moderation model in R's Lavaan package with an ordinal, dichotomous dependent variable. However, after defining the model and attempting to run summary statistics, I receive an error:

> Error in lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,
> :    lavaan ERROR: some variables have no values (only missings) or no
> variance

The code for the model looks like this:

```
Mod <- data.frame(X, W, Y)

ModerationModel_defined <-
  '  #regressions
              Y ~ b1*X + b2*W + b3*X:W
              
              SD.below := b1 + b3*(W1)
              low := b1+b3*(W2)
              median := b1+b3*(W3)
              mean := b1 + b3*(W4)
              SD.above := b1 + b3*(W5)
              high := b1+b3*(W6)
'

ModerationModel <- (lavaan::sem( ModerationModel_defined, std.lv = TRUE, data = Mod, meanstructure = TRUE))

summary(ModerationModel)
```

The output from attempting to get the summary statistics looks like this:

```
          name idx nobs    type exo user          mean         var nlev lnam
1            Y   3  350 ordered   0    0            NA          NA    2 0|1
2            X   1  350 numeric   1    0  1.374463e-15 354.5341940    0                   
3            W   2  350 numeric   1    0 -6.897529e-17   0.4222731    0                   
4***       X:W  NA    0    NULL   1    0            NA          NA    0
```

This output seems to suggest that the interaction term has no values, or else it has no variance.

However, when I check this independently there do not appear to be any missing values, and I am able to generate variance estimates.

```
> any_na(X*W)
[1] FALSE
> var(X*W)
[1] 62.22732
> sd(X*W)
[1] 7.888429
```

I can also view the data for this variable and see that every single entry has datum.

I am getting this error irrespective of whether I set the interaction term outside Lavaan (e.g., "WX <- X*W") or inside Lavaan (e.g., "XW := X:W").

Please note that X, Y and W are all mean centered.

I am also having this issue for a moderated mediation model I want to run. The simple mediation models run fine.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What happens if you just solve your regression model directly with `lm()` instead of through `lavaan`?

Comment: Or rather, use `glm()` so you can set `family = binomial(link = "probit")` (or `link = "logit") for the binary `Y`.  You can probe the interaction (calculate/test simple slopes) at least as easily as in `lavaan`, using the `interactions` package.